# How to interept the result on graphql relations resolver with middleware in apollo server?

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo-server, graphql-compose

I have a graphql type `UserReview` and `UserReply`:

```
type UserReview {
  _id
  content
}

type UserReply {
  _id
  reviewId
  content
}
```

I'm using [graphql-compose](https://github.com/graphql-compose/graphql-compose-mongoose) to do add a relation between reviews and replies so that when querying a review I will also get a list associated replies with the review - **this works**. Now I want to perform some data manipulation on the result. First I tried adding resolver middleware in graphql-compose. But the result of `userReviews` resolver is just an array of reviews without replies. After adding some `console.log` statements I noticed that the relation which populates the replies field of review is run after reviews resolver is run which makes sense because child resolver needs parent data first.

But I still need to somehow intercept the result before it's returned to the client. So I thought maybe I need to intercept it not at graphql-compose level but on graphql server lever (I'm using Apollo server). So I added another kind of [middleware](https://github.com/prisma-labs/graphql-middleware#standalone-usage):

```
import { applyMiddleware } from 'graphql-middleware'
import { schemaComposer } from 'graphql-compose'
export { UserReviewTC, UserReplyTC } from './UserReview'

const userReviewsMiddleware = {
  Query: {
    userReviews: async (resolve, parent, args, context, info) => {
      const result = await resolve(parent, args, context, info);
      // the result here still doesn't include replies!
      return result;
    }
  }
};
export const schema = applyMiddleware(
  schemaComposer.buildSchema(),
  userReviewsMiddleware
);
```

but still the result from `userReviewsMiddleware` doesn't include replies field. My question is how to actually get the complete result with replies before it's returned to the client?

**EDIT:** I see that there's `formatResponse` in Apollo [docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/api/apollo-server/) but it feels not right to perform data manipulation in `formatResponse` because I'd need to import modules which query the database inside `formatQuery`.

Comment: What exactly kind of manipulations do you need ? ... probably can be done with normal resolvers.

Comment: I'm using built-in graphql-compose resolvers to do the heavy lifting so I don't want to write my own resolver unless there're no other options.